# resume and continue training from exactly where it was stopped (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am training a huge dataset (each epoch needs 9 hours (with GPU) and there are 16 epochs).
Because of Google Colab limited runtime, I need to save the model and I want it to continue from exactly where it was stopped.

I used the below code but it start training from the beginning.
when I want to resume it I run the cell number 4 instead of 3. Am I doing it right?

1

```
model. Compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics= ["accuracy"])
```

2

```
batch_size = 32
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    'best_model', 
    verbose=1, 
    save_weights_only=False,
    save_freq = 10*batch_size)
```

3

```
history = model. Fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch= train_generator.n // 16, validation_data=valid_generator,
                    validation_steps= valid_generator.n // 16, callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

4

```
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('best_model')
new_history = loaded_model.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch= train_generator.n // 16, validation_data=valid_generator,
                               va.lidation_steps= valid_generator.n // 16, callbacks=[cp_callback],shuffle=False)
```

Please help me if you know what the problem is. I don't know what to do,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify what is your issue?

Comment: it starts training from the beginning instead of where it was left